# how to change the axis limit based on original data after transforming the data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code, the problem is I want to keep the x limits as the original data (`failure`) and y data to be between 0, 1, or 0, 99.9999%. I want to do this without using `twinx` axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#data
failure = np.array([168, 202, 190, 197, 169, 214, 201, 219, 206, 198, 190, 183, 206, 218, 214, 206, 213, 202, 209, 206])

#get plotting position for pprbablity distribution plots
def plottingPositionOriginal(failure, a=0.3):
    x = np.sort(failure)
    n = len(x)
    F = []
    for i in range(1, len(failure)+1):
        F.append((i - a) / (n + 1 - 2 * a))
    
    y = np.array(F)
    return x, y

# transform the y axis so the plot appears linear
def plottingPositionFit(failure):
    t, F = plottingPositionOriginal(failure)
    x = np.log(t)
 
    y = np.log(-np.log(1 - F))
    beta, c = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    y_fit = beta * x + c

    return x, y, y_fit


X, Y, y_hat = plottingPositionFit(failure)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X, Y) 

ax.plot(X, y_hat) 

plt.show()
```

This is my current plot:

[image]

This is how I want the plot to look (minus the red lines):

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. What should the final plot look like? Your current plot has limits from ~5.1 to 5.4, but you seem to be asking for limits based on `failure`, which go from 168 to 219, which doesn't make any sense. And what are you looking to do for the y-axis? Please clarify.

Comment: @jared as you correctly said, I want the axis (or ticks) to be based on the original data (failure). the y axis limit should be 0 to 1

Comment: i also added an ideal plot

Comment: It seems like you're looking for someone to write your code for you rather than fix an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the data to Matplotlib in its original form, and specify scales for each axis to specify the transformation: for the x-axis the built in log scale is enough; for the y-axis you can create a custom scale.  Here I do that by defining `y_forward` and `y_inverse`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, MaxNLocator


#data
failure = np.array([168, 202, 190, 197, 169, 214, 201, 219, 206, 198, 190, 183, 206, 218, 214, 206, 213, 202, 209, 206])

# Define forward and inverse transformations for the y-axis
def y_forward(val):
    return np.log(-np.log(1 - val))

def y_inverse(val):
    return 1 - np.exp(-np.exp(val))

#get plotting position for pprbablity distribution plots
def plottingPositionOriginal(failure, a=0.3):
    x = np.sort(failure)
    n = len(x)
    F = []
    for i in range(1, len(failure)+1):
        F.append((i - a) / (n + 1 - 2 * a))
    
    y = np.array(F)
    return x, y

# transform the y axis so the plot appears linear
def plottingPositionFit(failure):
    t, F = plottingPositionOriginal(failure)
    x = np.log(t)
 
    y = y_forward(F)
    beta, c = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    y_fit = beta * x + c
    F_fit = y_inverse(y_fit)

    return t, F, F_fit


X, Y, y_hat = plottingPositionFit(failure)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X, Y) 
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_yscale("function", functions=(y_forward, y_inverse))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(10))

ax.plot(X, y_hat) 

plt.show()
```

[image]